# If $X \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ then $\int_{B} |X| < \epsilon $ for $P(B)< \delta$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{B}( \mathbb{R}), P)$ be a probability space
>   and $X \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ a random variable. Show that for any 
>   fixed $\epsilon>0$, there always exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all
>   $B \in \mathcal{B}$ with $P(B)< \delta$, we have     \begin{align*} 
>  \int_{B} |X| < \epsilon  \end{align*}

**What I did**
 \begin{align*} 
 \int_{B} |X| &= \int_{ B \cap \{ |X| <K \}}  |X| +\int_{ B \cap \{ |X| \ge K \}}  |X|\\
&=E \left[ |X| \mathbb{1}_{B \cap \{ |X| <K \}}\right]+E \left[ |X| \mathbb{1}_{B \cap \{ |X| \ge K \}}\right]\\
& \le E \left[ K \mathbb{1}_{B \cap \{ |X| <K \}}\right]+E \left[ |X| \mathbb{1}_{B \cap \{ |X| \ge K \}}\right]\\
&= K P(B \cap \{ |X| <K \})+E \left[ |X| \mathbb{1}_{B \cap \{ |X| \ge K \}}\right]\\
& \le K P(B)+E \left[ |X| \mathbb{1}_{B \cap \{ |X| \ge K \}}\right]\\
& \le K \delta+E \left[ |X| \mathbb{1}_{B \cap \{ |X| \ge K \}}\right]\\
& \le K \delta+E \left[ |X| \mathbb{1}_{ \{ |X| \ge K \}}\right]\\
\end{align*}
So, up to this point I am confident in what I did. This is what I did next in order to bound $E \left[ |X| \mathbb{1}_{B \cap \{ |X| \ge K \}}\right]$

As $K$ increases $E \left[ |X| \mathbb{1}_{B \cap \{ |X| \ge K \}}\right] \downarrow 0$. So, there exist some $K$ such that  $E \left[ |X| \mathbb{1}_{B \cap \{ |X| \ge K \}}\right] \le \epsilon/$.

Putting it all together we get
\begin{align*} 
 \int_{B} |X| \le K \delta +\epsilon/2
\end{align*}

Finally, choose $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2K}$ and this concludes the proof.

The above is what I did. Is there something wrong with this argument can it be improved? Thank you for you comments.

Comment: This is correct except that you should replace $E \left[ |X| \mathbb{1}_{B \cap \{ |X| \ge K \}}\right]$ by $E \left[ |X| \mathbb{1}_{\{ |X| \ge K \}}\right]$ as soon as possible, then rely on the same arguments. Otherwise, one could get the impression that your $K$, hence the $\delta$ associated to some given $\epsilon$, also depend on $B$, which is forbidden.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a good argument that $E[|X| 1_{|X| \ge K}] \to 0$?  If you have one I can count that as your answer.

Comment: Dominated convergence theorem @Boby.

Comment: @StefanHansen what is dominating what?

Comment: $|X|\mathbf{1}_{|X|\geq K}\to 0$ pointwise as $K\to\infty$ and is dominated by the integrable $|X|$.

Comment: What @Stefan said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, observe that the sequence
$$f_n = |f|\chi_{\{|f|>n\}}$$
converges to $0$  pointwise a.e. and each $f_n \leq |f|$ .
Thus by dominated convergence theorem, we have
$$\lim_n \int_\mathbb{R} f_n = 0$$
Let $\epsilon$ be given, there exists an $N$ such that for every $n\geq N$, we have
$$\int_\mathbb{R} f_n <\epsilon,$$
choose $\delta = \mu (\{|f|>N\})$, then for each $B\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ with $\mu(B)<\delta$, we have
$$\int_B |f| \leq \int_{\{|f|>N\}} |f| = \int_\mathbb{R} f_N < \epsilon.$$

Comment: Is it necessarily so that $\int_B |f|\mathrm d\mu\leq \int_{\{|f|>N\}} |f|\mathrm d\mu$ just because $\mu(B)\leq \mu(\{|f|>N\})$. Don't we need the stronger assumption that $B\subseteq \{|f|>N\}$?

Comment: @Stefan the inequality is true not only because what you mentioned, think about the property of the set {|f|>n} with the integral.

Comment: Since the fact that, for every $B$ such that $\mu(B)\leqslant\mu(\{|f|\gt N\})$, $$\int_B|f|\leqslant\int_{\{|f|\gt N\}}|f|,$$ has a level of complexity similar to (if not higher than) the question originally asked, one wonders if this answer can be considered as a solution.

Comment: For $\mu(B) \leq \mu(\{|f|>N\})$, $$\int_B |f| \leq \int_{\{|f|>N\}} |f|$$ is very intuitive and clear if one stare at it carefully enough, there is no need to write down any calculation. On the part of the set $B$ say $B_1$ that is not contained in $\{|f|>N\}$ we must have $|f|\leq N$ on $B_1$ and $$\int_{B_1}|f| \leq N \mu(B_1) \leq N (\{|f|>N\}\cap B^c) \leq \int_{\{|f|>N\}\cap B^c} |f|.$$

Comment: To stare at $\ne$ to provide a proof. Yes one can prove this (who said otherwise?) but the question (that you never mention) is *whether this helps an OP asking this question to solve it*. Here is a suggestion: stop this barrage of nonconstructive nonsense, correct/complete your answer, and let us be done with it.

Comment: This is the exact argument in Terence Tao's analysis book, sorry if the last step wasn't clear to you.

Comment: You just made my point, do you realize that? And no, the childish provocation "the last step wasn't clear to you" won't work, sorry. (Unrelated: why not use @?)

Comment: @Did why would you take it as a provocation? I said "it wasn't clear to you" not "something you don't understand".  You assumed that OP (or any other reader) could not understand the last line of the proof and said it had a level of complexity similar to or even higher than the original question.

Comment: Yes I said that, hence your "unclear to you" (not "unclear to the OP" or "unclear to the casual reader") was a childish provocation. That, or you don't know what you write.